# Combine columns after joining tables in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I am still new to SQL and I want to do the following thing:

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Table 1:
Name        Date
BR03        04/2016
BR03        03/2018
BR04        02/2018
```

and

```
Table 2:
Name        Date
BR04        02/2012
BR03        03/2013
BR04        08/2019
```

Is there a way to join both tables and get:

```
Table
Name        Date
BR03        04/2016
BR03        03/2018
BR03        03/2013
BR04        02/2018
BR04        02/2012
BR04        08/2019
```

Instead of having them in two different columns?

Thanks!

Comment: What if there are two same records in this two tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to `join` them.  But the more common operation would be `union all`:

```
select name, date from table1
union all
select name, date from table2;
```

If you really wanted a join, you could use:

```
select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
       coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on false;
```